# Prefix in recursion does not work correctly

Tags: java, recursion

This is my code:

```
class Backwards {
    String str;
    Backwards(String s) {
        str = s;
    }

    void backward(int idx) {
        if(idx != str.length()-1) {
            System.out.println(idx);
            backward(++idx);
        }
        System.out.print(str.charAt(idx));
    }
}

class StrBackDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Backwards s = new Backwards("This is a test");
        s.backward(0);
    }
}
```

when I call function itself with expression `idx +1` it works nicely, but with `++idx`, it prints first character twice and doesn't print last character at all.

```
With <+idx> output: ttset a si sih
With <idx +1> output: tset a si sihT
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between `++idx` and `idx++`?

Comment: difference yes, but in this case i dont know difference between ++idx and idx +1, if idx = 12, in both cases function takes 13, because in ++idx, 12 firstly is increased, as in idx +1

Comment: So you do **not** know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

++i will increment the value of i, and then return the incremented value.

```
 i = 1;
 j = ++i;
 (i is 2, j is 2)
```

i++ will increment the value of i, but return the original value that i held before being incremented.

```
 i = 1;
 j = i++;
 (i is 2, j is 1)
```

So in your code cosider for idx =0 ;

```
System.out.println(idx); //idx = 0;
            backward(++idx); //its changed idx = 1 and passed 1 to this function
 System.out.print(str.charAt(idx));//After all recursion call here idx =1 not idx =0;
```

Hence you are getting wrong result

but in case of idx+1;

```
System.out.println(idx); //idx = 0;
                backward(idx+1); //its changed idx = 0 but passed 1 to this function
     System.out.print(str.charAt(idx));//After all recursion call here idx =0
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens cause on the the recursive call `backward(++idx)` you pass incremented value and also increment value itself. 
Operator `++` sets value of `idx` to `idx + 1`
On the last call you finish with situation when method gets index 13 and print char for it and the previous call also has index 13. In same time first call of method has index 1.

To fix your code use:

```
    void backward(int idx) {
        if(idx != str.length()-1) {
            System.out.println(idx);
            backward(idx + 1);
        }
        System.out.print(str.charAt(idx));
    }
```

With use of `idx + 1` value of `idx` will stay same where it is called.